# Find Names that SharePoint doesn't allow before copying to Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, file

Is there a way using Windows Explorer to find Names that SharePoint doesn't allow?  I have a user I need to move a large number of files from a users Windows Document folder to SharePoint.

If there are other recommended ways to find the files I'm o.k with that.  The files are on a Windows 2003 server.

Comment: What makes a file name illegal? Do you mean file names that SharePoint doesn't allow?

Comment: this could include file extensions and specific characters I'm assuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell script in this article allows you to scan an entire folder structure, including subfolders, and report on all files and folders containing one or more of the conditions listed above. There are also options within the script to automatically rename illegal characters in file names with something acceptable to SharePoint – for example, renaming the & symbol with the word ‘and’.

To use the script, first load the following function in a PowerShell console. Note that loading the function will not actually do anything until you call it later from the command line:

```
function Check-IllegalCharacters ($Path, [switch]$Fix, [switch]$Verbose)
{
    Write-Host Checking files in $Path, please wait...
    #Get all files and folders under the path specified
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
        #Check if the item is a file or a folder
        if ($item.PSIsContainer) { $type = "Folder" }
        else { $type = "File" }

        #Report item has been found if verbose mode is selected
        if ($Verbose) { Write-Host Found a $type called $item.FullName }

        #Check if item name is 128 characters or more in length
        if ($item.Name.Length -gt 127)
        {
            Write-Host $type $item.Name is 128 characters or over and will need to be truncated -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        else
        {
            #Got this from http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/05/20/finding-multiple-regex-matches.aspx
            $illegalChars = '[&{}~#%]'
            filter Matches($illegalChars)
            {
                $item.Name | Select-String -AllMatches $illegalChars |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values
            }

            #Replace illegal characters with legal characters where found
            $newFileName = $item.Name
            Matches $illegalChars | ForEach-Object {
                Write-Host $type $item.FullName has the illegal character $_.Value -ForegroundColor Red
                #These characters may be used on the file system but not SharePoint
                if ($_.Value -match "&") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "&", "and") }
                if ($_.Value -match "{") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "{", "(") }
                if ($_.Value -match "}") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "}", ")") }
                if ($_.Value -match "~") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "~", "-") }
                if ($_.Value -match "#") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "#", "") }
                if ($_.Value -match "%") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "%", "") }
            }

            #Check for start, end and double periods
            if ($newFileName.StartsWith(".")) { Write-Host $type $item.FullName starts with a period -ForegroundColor red }
            while ($newFileName.StartsWith(".")) { $newFileName = $newFileName.TrimStart(".") }
            if ($newFileName.EndsWith(".")) { Write-Host $type $item.FullName ends with a period -ForegroundColor Red }
            while ($newFileName.EndsWith("."))   { $newFileName = $newFileName.TrimEnd(".") }
            if ($newFileName.Contains("..")) { Write-Host $type $item.FullName contains double periods -ForegroundColor red }
            while ($newFileName.Contains(".."))  { $newFileName = $newFileName.Replace("..", ".") }

            #Fix file and folder names if found and the Fix switch is specified
            if (($newFileName -ne $item.Name) -and ($Fix))
            {
                Rename-Item $item.FullName -NewName ($newFileName)
                Write-Host $type $item.Name has been changed to $newFileName -ForegroundColor Blue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once loaded, you can call the script using the following commands as examples:

```
Check-IllegalCharacters -Path C:\Files
```

The command above will check the folder path specified but will only report file and folder names detected with illegal characters or length.

```
Check-IllegalCharacters -Path C:\Files -Verbose
```

This command will also only report files and folder names detected with illegal characters or length, but this time it will also tell you names of the files and folders it has checked in the process. This can be used to make sure the script is checking all the locations you are expecting it to.

```
Check-IllegalCharacters -Path C:\Files -Fix
```

More read here: http://get-spscripts.com/2011/11/use-powershell-to-check-for-illegal.html